# Serialize data to XML and CSV

Tags: c#, xml, csv, serialization

I have two problem. I need to serialize data to csv and xml but its turn out to be problematic for me.

As xml I desire to get something like:

```
<sentence>
 <word>example1</word>
 <word>example2</word>
 <word>example3</word>
</sentence>
<sentence>
 <word>example1</word>
 <word>example2</word>
 <word>example3</word>
</sentence>
```

My data its SentencedModel which contain inside collection of WordsModel. So it like: `List<ICollection<string>>.` Every position (sentence) in list have collection of string (words).
Class look like:

```
[Serializable]
public class WordsModel : IEnumerable<string>
{
    [XmlRoot("Word")]
    public ICollection<string> Words { get; set;}

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Words.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Words.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SentencedModel : IEnumerable<WordsModel>
{
    [XmlArray("Sentence"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(WordsModel), ElementName = "Words")]
    public ICollection<WordsModel> Sentences { get; set; }

    public SentencedModel()
    {
        this.Sentences = new List<WordsModel>();
    }

    public void Add(WordsModel words)
    {
        this.Sentences?.Add(words);
    }

    public IEnumerator<WordsModel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Sentences.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Sentences.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

My class which is Repositories for that:

```
public class WordsSeperapedBySentence
{
    public SentencedModel WordsSeperatedBySentence { get; }

    public WordsSeperapedBySentence()
    {
        this.WordsSeperatedBySentence = new SentencedModel();
    }

    public bool AddSentence(ICollection<string> words)
    {
        if (words == null) return false;
        WordsModel wordsModel = new WordsModel();
        wordsModel.Words = words;
        this.WordsSeperatedBySentence.Add(wordsModel);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my serializer class:

```
public class SerializeData
{
    public string SerializeToXml(SentencedModel data)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SentencedModel));
        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, data);
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public ToCsv(WordsSeperapedBySentence data)
    {
        //??
    }
}
```

But after using

```
List<string> example1 = new List<string>();
example1.Add("Chris"); 
example1.Add("call");
example1.Add("Anna");

List<string> example2 = new List<string>();
example2.Add("Somebody");
example2.Add("call");
example2.Add("Wolf");

WordsModel words1 = new WordsModel();
WordsModel words2 = new WordsModel();
words1.Words = example1;
words2.Words = example2;

SentencedModel sentenced = new SentencedModel();
sentenced.Add(words1);
sentenced.Add(words2);

SerializeData serialize = new SerializeData();
var stringAsResult = serialize.SerializeToXml(sentenced);
Console.WriteLine(stringAsResult);
```

I got errors. Also I do not have idea how to storage them to CSV. 
Could you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `I have two problem` and `I got errors` is not at all helpful, nor is asking two questions in one post.  Writing to CSV should be as simple as joining the words separated by `,` and writing the result out.

Comment: Yes it's true. Currently I've find some time and started read about XmlBuilder. Maybe later I will publish question number two just to XML. CSV is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save your data as CSV, you can use the following method which provides this output:

```
Chris,call,Anna
Somebody,call,Wolf
```

Each line is a sentence then all the words are separated by commas.

```cs
public string ToCsv(SentencedModel data)
{
    var csvLines = data.Select(x => String.Join(",", x));
    var csv = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, csvLines);
    return csv;
}
```

I am still missing the XML part, if I do, I will edit the answer.
At least you have a part of it.

**Edit** Please find below the `ToCsv` with the fields being escaped based on the comments below.

```cs
public string ToCsv(SentencedModel data)
{
    var csvLines = data.Sentences.Select(x => String.Join(",", x.Words.Select(w => EscapeForCsv(w))));
    var csv = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, csvLines);
    return csv;
}

private string EscapeForCsv(string input)
{
    return String.Format("\"{0}\"", input.Replace("\"", "\"\"\""));
}
```

Comment: For csv you might want to add that in some cases the strings need to be quoted and quotes inside that string then need to be escaped with another quote (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42719763/5708620 ).

Comment: Thanks. Went for the easy solution of escaping everything regardless. Could you provide the source for this CSV escaping rule? I would like to read further about it. Thanks.

Comment: There's not really a standard for csv, but RFC 4180 explains most of it - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 0):

First: If you want to tokenize a text - I recommend:

1. use an array and not a list. For example: string[][]. The reason: List will locate 10%-20% more memory. You can convert a List to Array by .ToArray() (e.g. example1.ToArray) or use the C# 6.0 syntax:

`string[][] sentence = new [] { {"Chris","called","Anna"}, {"Somebody","called","Wolf"} };`

2. If possible: use the primitive datatypes - classes are to complex and slowdown your textprocessing.

Second: If you want to implement your own serializer try this approce:

```
public abstract class AbstractSerializer
{
  public abstract void Serialize(string[][] model, string path);
}

public class XmlSerializer : AbstractSerializer
{
  public override void Serialize(string[][] model, string path)
  {
    // your stuff
  }
}

public class CsvSerializer : AbstractSerializer
{
  public string LineSeparator { get; set; } = "\r\n";
  public string ValueSeparator { get; set; } = ";";

  public override void Serialize(string[][] model, string path)
  {
    var stb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.Length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < model[i].Length; j++)
      {
        // Example output:
        // 0;0;Chris
        // 0;1;call
        // 0;2;Anna
        // 1;0;Somebody
        // 1;1;call
        // 1;2;Wolf
        stb.Append(string.Join(ValueSeparator, i, j, model[i][j], LineSeparator));
      }
    }
  }
}
```